# Apply function to each element of multiple lists; return differently named dataframes

Tags: python, list, function, dataframe

I have a function that returns specific country-currency pairs that are used in the following step.
The return is something like:

```
lst_dolar = ['USA_dolar','Canada_dolar','Australia_dolar']
lst_eur = ['France_euro','Germany_euro','Italy_euro']
lst_pound=['England_pound','Scotland_pound','Wales_pound']
```

I then use a function that returns a dataframe.
One of the parameters of this function is country-currency pair and the other is the period, from a list of periods:

```
period_lst = ['1y','2y','3y','4y','5y']
```

What I would like to do is to then get a list of dataframes, that will be then saved, each single one of them, to a different table, using SQLite3.

My question is how do I apply my function to each element of the lists of country-currency pairs and for each element of the period_lst and then obtain differently named dataframes as a result?

Ex: USA_dolar_1y

I then would like to be able to take each one of these dataframes and saved them to a table, in a database, that has the same name as each dataframe.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you think you need to dynamically name variables in Python, you probably want a dictionary:

```
def my_func(df, period):
    # do something with period and dataframe and return the result
    return df


period_lst = ['1y', '2y', '3y', '4y', '5y']
usa_dollar= {}
for p in period_lst:
    usa_dollar[p] = my_func(df, p)
```

You can then access the various resulting dataframes (or whatever your function returns) by their period:

```
use_data(usa_dollar['3y'])
```

By the way: don't use capitals in your variable names, you should reserve CamelCase for class names and write function names and variable names in lowercase, separated by underscores for readability. So, `usa_dollar`, not `USAdollar`, for example.

This helps editors spot problems in your code and makes the code easier to read for other programmers, as well as future you. Look up PEP8 for more of these style rules.

Another by the way: if the only reason you want to keep the resulting dataframes in separate variables is to then write them to a file, you could just write the dataframe to the file once you've created it, and reuse the variable for the next one, if you have no immediate other need for the data you're about to overwrite.

Comment: Hi @Grismar, thank you very much for your answer and for the warnign concerning the CamelCase.

So on this example, I want to produce 5*3=18 dataframes. Then I wish to save each dataframe onto a different database table using Sqlite3.

So my question here is, should I use a nested for loop, to iterate through each currency list (ex.:euro_lst, dollar_lst) and through each time period (ex.: 1y,2y,3y)? And then use your function to name each df separately? How could I invoque each of them separately then, to save each df on a separate database table? Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll find 5*3 to be 15 :). You can do it with for loops, sure, or any way you like. Just look up the dictionary `dict` type and how it works in Python - I already answered those questions in the answer above, please have another look and see if you understand the `dict` data type.

Comment: ahahhahahhaa yeah I actually had 5 here and 6 on my project! xD will do it now, thanks!